# Convert list of keys into JSON format

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Given the structure:

```
public class ProjectKey
{
    public string Key;
    public bool Parent;
}
```

Where a `List<ProjectKey>` is given in alphabetical order with the following values:

```
Key                 Parent
--------------------------
text                   1
text.ui                1
text.ui.hello          0
text.ui.goodbye        0
text.ui.popup          0
text.ui.project        1
text.ui.project.val    0
text.ui.project.val2   0
```

How can I easily convert this into JSON format with empty values?  For example, the above list would give the output:

```
{
    "text": {
        "ui": {
            "hello": "",
            "goodbye": "",
            "popup": "",
            "project":{
                "val": "",
                "val2": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way JSON.net can serialise in this way for me?  Or do I need to write my own converter?

Comment: You are going to have to parse these objects yourself. The good thing is that since you already know the custom layout, it shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: You can at least post a compilable code, so that we don't have to write a code to fill that list with your given values.

Comment: @TravisJ thanks, thought as much.  These things always fiddly though so thought I'd check!

Comment: Are you forced to use this JSON structure? Looks kinda silly to me...

Comment: @DrKoch yes, must be JSON

Comment: Yes of course, JSON is fine. But there are much better ways to store a tree like yours into a JSON file...

Comment: @DrKoch This is a good way to store the tree for the purposes we're using it for.  It's complicated so debate over this design choice in comments isn't going to be helpful for either of us!

Comment: @TomGullen Maybe you could to create JSON by runtime created class using `TypeBuilder`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Might be easier to transform your `List<ProjectKey>` into something else first and then serialize it. You'll probably end up needing to do it for custom serialization anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JObject` in JSON.NET seems particularly well-suited for something like this if you don't want to create a custom type to represent your hierarchy:

```
public string SerializeProjectKeys(List<ProjectKey> pks)
{
    JObject toSerialize = new JObject();

    foreach (ProjectKey pk in pks)
    {
        string[] keyParts = pk.Key.Split('.');
        JObject currentObj = toSerialize;

        for (int i = 0; i < keyParts.Length; i++)
        {
            string keyPart = keyParts[i];

            if (i == keyParts.Length - 1)
            {
                if (pk.Parent)
                {
                    currentObj.Add(keyPart, new JObject());
                }
                else 
                {
                    currentObj.Add(keyPart, string.Empty);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                currentObj = (JObject)currentObj[keyPart];
            }
        }
    }

    return toSerialize.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Ah this is brilliant exactly what I was after thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I am aware that JSON operations on strings are not so good. But I never created JSON objects using C# yet. Probably your question does not contain every data, but I think this might help a little bit about main idea:

```
        List<ProjectKey> projectKeys = new List<ProjectKey>();

        projectKeys.Add(new ProjectKey("text", true));
        projectKeys.Add(new ProjectKey("text.ui", true));
        projectKeys.Add(new ProjectKey("text.ui.hello", false));
        projectKeys.Add(new ProjectKey("text.ui.goodbye", false));
        projectKeys.Add(new ProjectKey("text.ui.popup", false));
        projectKeys.Add(new ProjectKey("text.ui.project", true));
        projectKeys.Add(new ProjectKey("text.ui.project.val", false));
        projectKeys.Add(new ProjectKey("text.ui.project.val2", false));

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < projectKeys.Count; i++)
        {
            if (projectKeys[i].Parent)
            {
                // If current key is parent - do not close bracket.
                output.AppendLine(string.Format("\"{0}\": {{", projectKeys[i].Key.Split('.').Last()));
            }
            else
            {
                // If this is no ones parent - close bracket.
                output.AppendLine(string.Format("\"{0}\": \"\"", projectKeys[i].Key.Split('.').Last()));
            }
        }

        // Append as many closing brackets as there are many parents.
        for (int i = 0; i < projectKeys.Where(x => x.Parent).Count(); i++)
        {
            output.AppendLine("}");
        }

        Console.Write(output.ToString());
```

IMHO this is weird kind of tree to contain information "am I parent" - I suggest to contain "my parent" property.

Comment: Read the comments below Travis J's answer.

Comment: I wrote that I'm aware this is not best solution but this might help with getting main idea. Read post, not just code. :)